# Что такое бинарно-безопасные функции в php?

Tags: php

И в чём заключается бинарная опасность других функций?
Например: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fwrite.php fwrite — Бинарно-безопасная запись в файл

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это значит, что функция пригодна для обработки не только простого текста, но и бинарных данных. Ничего при этом потеряно или искажено не будет.

Иногда бывает нужно работать именно с бинарными данными. Например, что-нибудь сгенерировать объёмное, а результат надо сжать в gzip функцией `gzencode`. Эта функция вернёт строку бинарных данных. Или функции шифрования данных нередко отдают именно бинарное представление - просто потому, что оно занимает меньше памяти, а во что-нибудь текстовое при необходимости можете преобразовать уже вы.

Функции, не отмеченные как бинарно безопасные, могут исказить значение или неверно обработать (например, в районе символа NUL), т.к. рассчитаны на работу с текстом. А бинарно-безопасные - отработают корректно, какие байты сказали записать - те и будут записаны.